# viewportChecker и анимация

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animate

Использую `viewportChecker` и `Animate.css` , допустим анимация bounceInLeft. Но вот проблема, при появлении блока в зоне видимости он сначала стоит на своем месте, на долю секунды, потом исчезает и уже потом выезжает слева. Как сделать так что бы блок сразу выезжал. Использовал параметр `offset: 0` , в итоге время задержки просто уменьшилось(если делать прокрутку медленно, если быстро проблема исчезает), а проблема осталась.

Comment: viewportChecker не юзал. Можно его заменить на WOW.js

Comment: @РусскийМедведь попробую но все же viewport оставить хочется, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нужно скрыть его перед тем, как он проанимирует.

```
$('.two .center-content').addClass('hidden-my').viewportChecker({
   classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeIn',
   offset: 100
  });
```

Sass:

```
.hidden-my
  opacity: 0
```